# How can i draw direction (route) using google map api?

Tags: ios4, google-maps, mkmapview

I want to draw a route using google api please suggest me is there any google api is available for drawing route between 2 latitude and Longitude.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString * urlString = nil;

    urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@",12.58, 77.35, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",[detailInfoDict valueForKey:@"address"],[detailInfoDict valueForKey:@"city"],[detailInfoDict valueForKey:@"state"]]];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using this way as well.
Step 1:
Add this Frameworks

[image]

Step 2: Imports these files into your View Controllers .h file
[image]

Step 3: Provide 2 Location's latitude and longitude in ViewControllers' .m file

[image]

OutPut:You will get output like this

[image]

Comment: From Where we supposed to find that two files ? (Mapview.h and place.h) you have to specify here.

Comment: can you provide these (Mapview.h and place.h) files ?

Comment: Are you sure this is a legal and allowed by Google?